# How to withdraw ether from reference of a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, solidity-0.8.x

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract acceptETH {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public price;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    constructor (){
        owner = msg.sender;
        price = 2 ether;
    }
    function accept() public payable {
        require(msg.value == price);
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
    function retContractBalance() public view returns(uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function withdraw() payable external {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success);
    }
}
contract newETH{
    acceptETH internal acceth;
    constructor(){
        acceth = new acceptETH();
    }
    
    function Accept() external payable {
        acceth.accept{value: msg.value}();
    }
    function Balance() external view returns(uint256){
        return acceth.retContractBalance();
    }
    function Withdraw() payable external {
        acceth.withdraw();
    }
}
```

In this Code **newETH** contract is not able to **Withdraw** from **acceptETH**.
Well i'm new to smart Contracts, so i've no idea if this is possible?
Any way to do it?
Main goal is to transfer all ethers from acceptETH contract to the owner.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 2 simpile ways:

1. Create a **receive** function in the **newETH** Contract to accept ether from outside. And to forward it to the owner, just transfer those ethers directly to the owner or via a function it's upto one's preference.
   Here, is the implementation of the same. I've also included some additional functions play with them and the concept will be clear(Hint: just Notice addresses carefully).

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract acceptETH {
    address public owner;
    uint256 public price;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    constructor (){
        owner = msg.sender;
        price = 2 ether;
    }
    function accept() public payable {
        require(msg.value == price);
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }
    function retContractBalance() public view returns(uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function withdraw(address _ClaimOwner) external {
        //require(msg.sender == owner);
        (bool success, ) = _ClaimOwner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success);
    }
    function getOwner() external view returns(address) {
        return owner;
    }
    function AEaddress() external view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }
    function getmsgsender() external view returns(address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
}
contract newETH{
    acceptETH internal acceth;
    address public owner;
    constructor(){
        acceth = new acceptETH();
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function Accept() external payable {
        acceth.accept{value: msg.value}();
    }
    function acceptETHBalance() external view returns(uint256){
        return acceth.retContractBalance();
    }
    function newETHBalance() external view returns(uint256){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function Withdraw() external {
        acceth.withdraw(msg.sender);
    }
    receive() external payable{
        (bool success, ) = owner.call{value:msg.value}("");
        require(success);
    }
    function accethOwner() external view returns(address) {
        return acceth.getOwner();
    }
    function accethAddress() external view returns(address) {
        return acceth.AEaddress();
    }
    function accethmsgSender() external view returns(address) {
        return acceth.getmsgsender();
    }
    function thisAddress() external view returns(address) {
        return address(this);
    }
}
```

2. If you understood the above code, then it will be clear what's causing the problem in the first place. Thus, one more approach is to simply set **Owner** of **acceptETH** not by msg.sender but passing msg.sender from **newETH** contract. Voila it's solved.